# Mapping from normed linear space to a quotient space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

If $M$ is a closed linear subspace of a normed linear space $N$, and if $T$ is the natural mapping of $N$ onto $N/M$ defined by $T(x)$ = $x+M$, show that $T$ is a continuous linear transformation for which $||T||$ $\le 1$ .

This question is from GF Simmons's Introduction to Modern Analysis book. Now, I can prove why the mapping is linear but for other stuff, I have no clue. I am generally stumped when presented with problems involving quotient spaces. Also, how is $M$ being closed important?

Comment: You need the subspace to be closed to get that the usual norm on the quotient space is actually is a norm. See for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337406/mapping-from-normed-linear-space-to-a-quotient-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual norm on the quotient space is
$$ \Vert x + M \Vert_q := \inf_{m\in M} \Vert x + m \Vert. $$
Now you can use the definition of the operator norm to show $\Vert T \Vert_{op} \leq 1$. Indeed, we have $0\in M$ and thus
$$ \Vert T x\Vert_q = \Vert x + M \Vert_q = \inf_{m\in M} \Vert x + m \Vert
\leq \Vert x \Vert. $$
This implies $\Vert T \Vert_{op} \leq 1$.

As pointed out in my comment, we need $M$ to be closed for $\Vert \cdot \Vert_q$ to be a norm. Imagine for example you take a dense subspace, then infimum is always zero (ie it is not a norm, because it is not positive definite).

Comment: I did not understand the last line. How is it not positive definite if the infimum is always zero? And how is the infimum always zero for a dense subspace?

Comment: Because $\Vert x + M \Vert+0$, but $x+M\neq 0+M$. If $M$ is dense, then there is for every $\varepsilon>0$ some $x_\varepsilon \in M$ such that $\Vert x - x_\varepsilon \Vert < \varepsilon$ and if you take the infimum you simply get $0$.